# New line in email body after each field

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have the following code for a form in my site for reservations, but the email I'm getting has all the information of the form cramped up, and need to separate each field in a new line. Must be pretty easy for anyone, I'm just not good at code.

```
<form <?php echo !empty($post_options['id']) ? ' id="'.esc_attr($post_options['id']).'"' : ''; ?> data-formtype="<?php echo esc_attr($post_options['layout']); ?>" method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url($post_options['action'] ? $post_options['action'] : admin_url('admin-ajax.php')); ?>">
        <?php jarvis_sc_form_show_fields($post_options['fields']); ?>
        <div class="sc_form_info">
            <div class="sc_form_item sc_form_field none"><input type="text" name="eventname" value="<?php echo (!empty($eventname)) ? esc_attr($eventname) : esc_html__('Any', 'jarvis'); ?>"></div>
            <div class="sc_form_item sc_form_field label_over"><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e('Name', 'jarvis'); ?>"></div>
            <div class="sc_form_item sc_form_field label_over"><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e('E-mail', 'jarvis'); ?>"></div>
            <div class="sc_form_item sc_form_field label_over"><input type="number" name="number" min="1" max="1000" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e('Number of people', 'jarvis'); ?>"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sc_form_item sc_form_field date_time">
            <div class="sc_form_item sc_form_item_date sc_form_field label_top">
                <div class="sc_form_date_wrap icon-calendar-light">
                    <input placeholder="Date" class="js__datepicker" type="text" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sc_form_item sc_form_item_time sc_form_field label_top">
                <div class="sc_form_time_wrap icon-clock-empty">
                    <input placeholder="Time" class="js__timepicker" type="text" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sc_form_item sc_form_button"><button class="sc_button sc_button_style_border gradient_bd hover"><?php esc_html_e('Book the table', 'jarvis'); ?></button></div>
        <div class="result sc_infobox"></div>
    </form>
```

Help is appreciated. ;)

Comment: add a br tag after the div where you want to show it

Comment: Can you show us the code where you build the email message body? That's probably where you need to implement the fix.

Comment: @random-developer Will that add a new line to the message body, or the form
You see I don't have ftp access to the site I'm editing and if I screw up, I'm doomed

Comment: @rickdenhaan The whole php template?

Comment: @Dankosaurus yep, pretty much

Comment: @RandomDeveloper Tried it and it didn't work, still jammed up

Comment: @Dankosaurus To find out where the problem is, we need to see where you're putting the form values in the email message body. We probably won't need to see the whole template, just the part that's not behaving the way you want it to.

Comment: I suspect there is no style being sent with the email, this is done by adding a <style> block to the email body. But without code we cannot help.

Comment: @Chris I can't really find a style for this. It's basically some forms in .php files like the one in my question that are loaded into the visual composer plugin.

Comment: You supply the style along with the body text, basically you want to be sending a well formed html page. You will have to do some trial and error, emails are notoriously quirky about how they display html much along the lines of different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

add a `<br>` to add line breaks and start at a new line.

> The HTML element produces a line break in text (carriage-return). It
>   is useful for writing a poem or an address, where the division of
>   lines is significant.

See the example below

```html
<p>
Hi <br>
i <br>
am using multiple <br>
breaks <br>
</p>
```

Hope this helps!